# parameters are not being applied to the img

Tags: css

I am having trouble trying to edit my class parameters. I've given my img a class, and when I go to css and try to change parameters like "display, object-fit, border-radius, width, etc", css wont recognize it.

Here is what I have coded:

```
<div class="img-container" id="img-div">
<img 
src="https://imagens.ebc.com.br/Xfd7n6tdKqubij-UlWGOPQKQhlk=/1170x700/smart/https://agenciabrasil.ebc.com.br/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/52483379892_a0ecea7e5c_o.jpg?itok=b6o3tMQ4" alt="tite" class="tite-image" id="image" />
    <div class="caption" id="img-caption">
      Tite apresentando a lista de convocados para o mundial do Qatar.
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the css part:

```
.tite-image{
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius:10px;
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It worked on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4nsdv26w/
Is it the only css class that doesn't work ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the contents of your `<head>` tag, and show us what does your file structure looks like. Seems like your CSS file is not linked properly.

Comment: yes, the only one

Comment: <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="tribute to Mr. Adenor Leonardo Bacchi" />
    <title>Adenor Leoanrdo Bacchi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".styles.css"
    </head>

This is what the <head> looks like. 

The img dimensions are not changing as i especify it

Answer (score 0):

Look's like your code is good. Maybe something block it from above? Try to add your style to img-container:

```
.img-container img {
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius:10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: What could be blocking from above?

Comment: Other CSS code. As someone commented https://jsfiddle.net/sytrus/6vn3x4b8/ it worked perfeced on jsfiddle. Short way to find the problem - open your page in chrome dev tools and look inside elements > styles to find the problem